# Redirecting TCP traffic to another destination

Tags: windows

I have a game client. Which connects to this game. I'm trying to set up a socket server which intercepts all traffic to the game server(The game runs through the use of sockets)

My problem is that i would need to redirect all traffic my computer makes to the game servers ip + port to 127.0.0.1 to make it connect to the socket server i've made myself first.

I know i could use the windows hosts file but this redirects ALL traffic. I only want 1 port redirected(The one with TCP traffic) If the HTTP traffic also gets redirected it ruins everything.

I'm using windows 7
The programming language is java.

Comment: Programming question -> stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [Layered Service Provider (LSP)](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0599/layeredservice/layeredservice.aspx). What you need to do is intercept that operation that makes the connection and change the destination IP address (and possibly port). It's possible you might also need to intercept operations to get the remote socket address to make it consistent with what the application expected, but it's not likely. Applications don't usually check the remote address of TCP connections they initiated.

A simpler way is to hook the WSAConnect call the application makes and change the destination IP address directly. You could do this a number of ways. For example, you could use [Microsoft Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/). You could also give the application your own Winsock DLL that forwards operations to the regular one. There are numerous other API intercept methods as well.